# How to move from MySQL 5.0 to 5.5?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently on Windows 2003 using MySQL 5.0.54a and I'm moving to Linux which has MySQL 5.5.24.

Is this a simple exercise of using mysqldump to export the data from 5.0.54a and then import it into 5.5.24?

Or should I go through the upgrade steps, to bring in my data into a 5.1 instance before bringing it to 5.5.24?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mysql says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html) it's better to dump, then import into 5.1, then dump again, and finally import into 5.5.

Comment: I don't have 5.1 to upgrade to (and I don't think it was part of our plans either). If I was upgrading our current databases on Windows 2003, this would be the plan. However, as I mentionned, we're migrating to another standalone environment (in Linux) that already has 5.5 running.

Comment: I would not recommend doing an in place upgrade of Mysql. Simply spin up a Linux VM on which to install Mysql 5.1 for the import from 5.0 and to create a dump for your 5.5 server.

Answer (score 0):

After restoring using the mysqldump method do remember to run the [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html) script to fix the privileges table.